# Dynamic background image on tab click in Napili Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, customer-community, napili

I have a Napili community where I am using Standard **Tabs** component to show different standard and custom lightning component. I want to change the background image every time I clicked on the different tab (Not tab background). One image on one tab. How I can achieve that any guesses?

I am looking something like these images:-
[image: Background image on tab 1][image: Background image on tab 2][image: Background image on tab 3]

Answer (score 1):

Each tab has a different class, if you scope your CSS rules properly under community branding, you can easily achieve this.

Tab 1

[image]

Tab 2

[image]

You can use your browser dev tools to help you figure out the proper css scoping:

[image]

If you want to completely change the background of the community based on different tabs you have, you will have to create a [custom theme layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm) in order to be able to interact with the template body and within it use tabsets where you can use the onactive attribute to change the template body programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I am not looking to change background image of tab. I updated my question. Sorry for less information. Thanks ones again.

Comment: updated the answer